# Is it possible to import a Python module (.py file) into a dict?

Tags: python, python-import

Something along the lines of:

In one file:

```
FOO_CONST = 'bar'

def some_function(baz)
    return do_something_with(baz)

from somewhere import something

blah = something()
```

In another file:

```
my_stuff = import_as_dict("module")
```

And `my_stuff` would essentially be the equivalent of:

```
{
    'FOO_CONST': 'bar',
    'some_function': <function my_function at ...>,
    'blah': 'I am the result of calling the function "somewhere.something".',
}
```

Any libraries that could do that out of the box?

**UPDATE:**

Since `vars(module) == module.__dict__` I have upvoted two answers but have accepted the one with a bit more data. This is the code which returns pretty much exactly what I had in mind:

```
my_stuff = {(key, var) for key, var in vars(module).items() if not key.startswith('__')}
```

Comment: Your examples are kinda complicated. Hahaha.

Comment: No `'something': <function something ....>` in the result dictionary?

Comment: Actually you are correct, I would expect it to be there too. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import module
my_stuff = module.__dict__
```

Note that this dict is the actual dict the module uses to hold its attributes. If you do `my_stuff['foo'] = 3`, `module` has a new `foo` attribute equal to `3`.

If you just want to get attributes by names determined at runtime, you don't really need the dict. You could do

```
thing = getattr(module, thingname)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars)?

```
import module
my_stuff = vars(module)
```

Comment: You'll have to remove the special attributes with `__` though.

Comment: Three big guys in a question. I'd prefer to stay out of this.. T_T

Comment: If you *want* to remove the special attributes. It's not clear to me that `my_stuff['__file__']` should do anything different from `module.__file__`.

Comment: @aIKid Yup. Thats a rare thing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the way you access module members, you can use:

```
my_sys = import_as_dict("sys")
print my_os["sys"]
```

With the following code:

```
import imp


class DictProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, target):
        super(DictProxy, self).__init__()

        self.target = target

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.target, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self.target, key, value)


def import_as_dict(module_name):
    file_, pathname, description = imp.find_module(module_name)
    module = imp.load_module(module_name, file_, pathname, description)
    dict_module = DictProxy(module)
    return dict_module
```

Using `imp` for the imports will keep your global context clean.